# How can I get geocoder address to backing bean?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Using PrimeFaces p:gmap component.

I have a page with a gmap component with a set of markers.
I want to display the street address in the gmapInfoWindow and pass it to the backing bean as well.
When I click on the map marker, I call a javascript function to get the reverse geocoder address.
I can fetch the address and display it in a javascript alert dialog, but I can't get it to fill the backing bean variable or in the info marker.

The variable does get filled, but it does not get updated until the next time I click on the marker.
As a result, the addresses are always one marker click behind.

Does anyone know how I can get the address to update during the current page session?
Thanks.

The backing bean code onMapMarkerSelect just has a System.out.println statement to show the mapAddress variable.
Here is the page code:

```
                <h:form prependId="false" >
                     <p:gmap id="gmap" center="#{mappingSessionBean.mapCenter}" zoom="#{mappingSessionBean.mapZoom}" type="HYBRID" rendered="true"
                            style="#{mappingSessionBean.polygonGmapStyle}" onPointClick="handlePointClick(event);"
                            model="#{mappingSessionBean.mapModel}" fitBounds="#{mappingSessionBean.fitBoundsFlag}"
                            widgetVar="map" >
                        <p:ajax id="gmapAjax" event="overlaySelect" immediate="true" onstart="handlePointClick(event);" listener="#{mappingSessionBean.onMapMarkerSelect}" />
                        <p:gmapInfoWindow id="infoWindow" >
                            <p:outputPanel >
                                <h:panelGrid columns="1" >
                                    <h:outputText id="infoWindowTitle" value="#{mappingSessionBean.selectedMarker.title}" />
                                    <h:outputText id="infoWindowAddress" value="#{mappingSessionBean.mapAddress}" rendered="true" />
                                    <p:commandButton value="Zoom In" action="#{mappingSessionBean.selectedViewInfoListener}" update="gmap" />
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </p:gmapInfoWindow>
                    </p:gmap>
                    <h:inputHidden id="address" value="#{mappingSessionBean.mapAddress}" />
                </h:form >

        <script type="text/javascript" >
            function handlePointClick(event) {
                if(navigator.geolocation)
                {
                    browserSupportFlag = true;
                    var latlng = event.latLng;
                    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status)
                    {
                        if( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK )
                        {
                            alert( results[0].formatted_address );
                            document.getElementById('address').value = results[0].formatted_address;
                            document.getElementById('infoWindowAddress').value = results[0].formatted_address;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert( "Geocoder failed due to: " + status );
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    alert( "No Geolocation");
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general solution, I guess you can do better if you will find a way to trigger an event on inputHidden without the use of the button

b.t.w : jQuery comes with primefaces so you can use it without any additional includes

instead of

```
<h:inputHidden id="address" value="#{mappingSessionBean.mapAddress}" />
```

place

```
    <f:ajax listener="#{mappingSessionBean.myajax}" execute="address">
        <h:inputHidden  id="address" value="#{mappingSessionBean.mapAddress}" />
        <h:commandButton id="addressBtn" style="display:none"/>
    </f:ajax>
```

(you can replace execute="address" with execute="@form")

and in js code replace

```
document.getElementById('address').value = results[0].formatted_address;
```

with

```
jQuery("#address").val(results[0].formatted_address);
jQuery("#addressBtn").click(); // this will trigger the ajax listener
```

and finally in your bean add the implementation of the ajax listener itself

```
public void myajax(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    System.out.println(getMapAddress());
}
```